# Show UIActivityIndicator during segue navigation, after UIBarButtonItem press

Tags: objective-c, spinner, uibarbuttonitem, uiactivityindicatorview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UIBarButtonItem in the navigation bar which switches to another screen, using a segue. This other screen takes some time to initialize, and I wanted to put a UIActivityIndicator on the UIBarButtonItem to show the tap has been registered, and the iPad is busy executing the action.

My approach was to add a UIActivityIndicator to the UIBarButtonItem after it was pressed, then call `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, and in the `viewDidLoad` method of the second view, put the initialization into a `dispatch_sync()` call. You can guess it does not work... why?

The IBAction on the first screen:

```
- (void)tappedEdit: (UIBarButtonItem *)editButton {
    // put activity indicator somewhere
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
    indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    indicator.frame = CGRectMake (200, 5, 50, 50);
    [self addSubview: indicator];
    [indicator startAnimating];
    // follow segue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: SegueShowDesignMode sender: editButton];
    }
```

The initialization on the second screen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // put costly operations into another queue to free main queue for activity indicator
    dispatch_sync (dispatch_get_global_queue (0, 0), 
                   ^{ // do initialization here
                   });
}
```

The effect of this is that the UIBarButtonItem stays tapped while the initialization is performed, then the UIActivityIndicator is visible for a quick moment, and lastly the segue animation is shown, displaying the second screen.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Probably an addition to the problem is that the initialization does some UIKit stuff: When I tried to use a semaphore, the initialization dumps with a BAD ACCESS in some UITextView method. I guess this is because it runs on some 'get_global_queue' and not on the 'get_main_queue'.

EDIT AGAIN: Well, no. Using 'get_main_queue' results in a dead-lock, as announced in the Apple docs. So the question boils down to

"How can I do background UIView creation (lots of!) while still having a spinner running?"

Answer (score 1):

I think one problem is that you are using `dispatch_sync` in your `viewDidLoad` method in your second screen. `dispatch_sync` will block your thread until the block with `// do initialization here` has completed. Try changing it to `dispatch_async` instead.

The other thing I'd consider doing if I were you is getting the `UIActivityIndicator` to appear as part of the second screen, not the first. That way, the second screen can also dismiss it after your view has finished the costly operations. Of course, this assumes that the view can actually display before those operations have completed.

Comment: rickerbh, thanks for the hints. But dispatch_async() requires further synchronization, since the initialization builds up the view hierarchy to be displayed, and if this runs asynchronously, the views will not exist when the storyboard framework wants to display it. Please also see edited question.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a storyboard

ButtonBarItem.h

```
 #import "CheckWifi.h"

    interface LoadingViewController : UIViewController 

    -(IBAction)BarItemPressed:(id)sender;
```

ButtonBarItem.m:

```
-(IBAction)BarItemPressed:(id)sender {LoadingViewController *DIS = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CheckWifi"];
DIS.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:DIS animated:YES];}
```

LoadingViewController.h:

```
 @interface LoadingViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner

    }

-(IBAction)StopAnimating;

@end
```

LoadingViewController.m:

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad {

spinner.hidden = NO;

}

-(IBAction)StopAnimating {

    spinner.hidden = YES;

    }
```

If you're using an XIB File, then I cannot help you really, Sorry.

Comment: AaronLeanage, thanks for your reply. I have a few problems understanding what you propose, though: The ButtonBarItem.{hm} spelled out are the navigation bar button triggering the segue? Why are you presenting the controller "manually" in the 'BarItemPressed' method? As far as I read this code, it does not employ a segue..?! And secondly, assuming that your 'LoadingViewController' is the second controller showing up after the button press, how does it get access to the spinner defined in the previous scene (containing the 'ButtonBarItem'? I feel I'm not getting your proposal correctly.

Comment: This is definately a segue but i am saying that instead of putting the activity indicator into the first view (barbuttonitem), you should put it into the second view (loadingviewcontroller)